# thread waits in log4j

Tags: multithreading, log4j, wait

We are receiving thread locks (PFB the thread dump).Can you give us suggestion why we receive it.
Note that we use Java 1.5, weblogic 9.1 , log4j version 1.2.8

[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=2 tid=0x01d332b0 nid=0x23 waiting for monitor entry [0x5fffd000..0x5ffffb10]
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:185)
    - waiting to lock <0x7c669620> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootCategory)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:372)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:864)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.debug(Log4JLogger.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2150)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2029)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2024)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1093)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at com.lks.myapp.data.dao.SourceCheckImpl.getSources(SourceCheckImpl.java:87)

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? Last I heard log4j has source code available. I bet if you look at line 185 in Category.java, it'll tell you what it's waiting on.

Comment: check the below link. There are some performance issues with log4j1.2.x https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41214 This link captures your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to logback for high performance logging. Log4j is having performance issues. We have done the same in one of our products